# What is the specifier in an IP where the complement of the verb is fronted?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

In the sentence  (IP)

> `The book, I think that I gave you`

in which the object (complement of the verb of the CP "that I gave you") is fronted, is this fronted object the specifier of the whole IP? If not is there a specifier in this IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topicalised object *the book* which is fronted (moved) cannot land in a theta-position. It'll violate Visibility Condition on Chains. Remember this is a non-trivial A-chain, it must have one theta role and one case to be visible. Spec,IP of this sentence is a theta-position occupied by the subject *I*.

The only option remaining is a theta-bar position. Spec,CP is a nice candidate. From this position, it'll have scope (being a topic) over the clause without affecting theta/case properties:

[CP **the book** C' C ∅ [IP **I** I' I [VP V' V **think** [CP that I gave you **t** ]]]]

It's similar to:

The book that I think that I gave you.

The picture differs in pro-drop languages. Spec,IP is taken to be a theta-bar position even in active voices (Spanish, Italian, Arabic, etc.).